# How to retry topic reserver loss connection on azure service bus javascript client

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus, amqp, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am listing to a topic in azure service bus with the following javascript code.

Library and version @azure/service-bus 1.1.2

```
        const sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(
        config.merchant_event.connection_string
         );
        const topicClient = sbClient.createSubscriptionClient(
         config.merchant_event.topic_name,
         config.merchant_event.subcription_name
       );

  const receiver = topicClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

  receiver.registerMessageHandler(
      merchantEventMessageHandler,
      merchantEventErrorHandler
    );
```

As soon as the application starts, it working fine. But if any case connection loss or connection time out, the listener will stop listening.

Can you please advise how to address this. Is there any retry mechanism to enable for reconnect the connection if it is a loss.

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

If the clients had gone into a bad state due to the connection loss, you'd need to re-create the clients/receivers in Version 1 `@azure/service-bus` SDK. Here is a related issue on GitHub that talks about the `registerMessageHandler` and retries - [azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11914](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11914).

However, I'd recommend you leverage the `subscribe` method that is offered in version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK instead.

#### Version 7

You can leverage the `subscribe` method if you want to receive the messages **forever**(you can stop receiving as needed).

`subscribe` handles the disconnects and reconnections gracefully and is capable of recovering even from fatal errors such as entity-not-found.

You can refer to the [receiveMessagesStreaming.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/typescript/src/receiveMessagesStreaming.ts) sample code that uses version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus node SDK and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)